# adding more icon to react native drawer

Tags: react-native

Hi everyone I want to add one more icon to my custom drawer in the react native app project that i'm woking on for practise. Please help me out how i can achieve the result shown in picture the last picture( i want to add ">" this arrow icon on every column. )

```
    const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

   export default function AppStack() {
    return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
        drawerContent={props =>

            <CustomDrawer{...props} />
        }

        screenOptions={{
            drawerStyle: {
                width: wp('100'),
                height: hp('83.5'),
                borderTopRightRadius: 35,
                borderTopLeftRadius: 35,
                top: hp('4'),
            },
            headerShown: false
        }}
    >
        <Drawer.Screen name="MyProfile" component={ProfileScreen}
            options={{
                drawerIcon: () => (
                    <Ionicons name="person-outline" size={26}
                        style={{ alignContent: 'space-between' }}
                    />
                )
                //                 < Image
                // source={ require('./chats-icon.png') }
                // style={ [styles.icon, { tintColor: tintColor }]}
                //             />
            }}
        />
        <Drawer.Screen name="MyTask" component={MyTask}
            options={{
                drawerIcon: () => (
                    <MaterialIcons name="edit" size={26} />
                )
            }}
        />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Queries" component={Queries}
            options={{
                drawerIcon: () => (
                    <View style={{ display: 'flex', borderBottomWidth: 1 }}>
                        <Ionicons name="timer-outline" size={26} />
                        <View>
                            <Ionicons name="timer-outline" size={40} />
                        </View>
                    </View>
                )
               }}
            />
         </Drawer.Navigator>
       )
      }
```

my custom drawer component:-

const CustomDrawer = (props: any) => {
return (
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>

```
        <DrawerContentScrollView {...props} style={{ flex: 8 }}>

            <View style={{
                alignItems: 'center', flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', paddingHorizontal: 20, paddingTop: 20
            }}>

                <View >
                    <Image source={require('../assets/bharat.png')}
                        style={{ height: 70, width: 70, borderRadius: 45, marginBottom: 10 }}
                    />
                </View>
                <View>
                    <Text style={{
                        fontFamily: 'lato',
                        fontStyle: 'normal',
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: '700',
                        color: '#545455'
                    }}>Bharat Kumar</Text>
                    <Text style={{
                        fontFamily: 'lato',
                        fontStyle: 'normal',
                        fontSize: 12,
                        fontWeight: '400',
                        color: '#5F488A'
                    }}>Your profile is 70% complete</Text>
                </View>
                <View>
                    <TouchableOpacity>
                        <Ionicons name="close-outline" size={30} color={'#111'} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>

            <View style={{
                borderBottomColor: '#D4D6DB',
                borderBottomWidth: 1,
                margin: hp('2')
            }}></View>

            <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
                <DrawerItemList {...props} />
            </View>
        </DrawerContentScrollView>

        <View style={{
            borderBottomColor: '#D4D6DB',
            borderBottomWidth: 1,
            margin: hp('2')
        }}></View>

        <View style={{ paddingHorizontal: 20, flex: 0.15 }}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { }}>
                <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center" }}>
                    <Ionicons name="exit-outline" size={26} />
                    <Text style={{
                        color: '#5F488A',
                        fontFamily: 'lato',
                        fontStyle: 'normal',
                        fontWeight: '400',
                        fontSize: 18,
                        marginLeft: 15
                    }}>
                        Log Out
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View >

    </View >
)
}

export default CustomDrawer
```

right now it's showing like this

[PictureOne](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fG3PE.jpg)

but I want it like this

[Picturetwo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4GCV.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

```
<Drawer.Screen
     name="Balances"
     component={BalancesScreen}
     options={{
       title: t('tab.balances'),
       drawerLabel: () => <DrawerItemLabel label={t('tab.balances')} />,
       drawerIcon: () => <BalancesIcon />
     }}
/>
```

Try something like this. In `drawerLabel` you can pass a component or another icon. In my example I pass another component with some props. For example I paste this component to clarify.

`example-component-to-clarify.tsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Badge from './Badge';
import View from './View';
import Text from './Text';
import { useTheme } from '@react-navigation/native';

const DrawerItemLabel = ({
  label,
  newCount
}: {
  label: string;
  newCount?: number;
}) => {
  const { colors } = useTheme();

  return (
    <View style={styles.wrapper}>
      <View style={styles.text}>
        <Text style={{ color: colors.contrastColor, fontWeight: '500' }}>
          {label}
        </Text>
      </View>
      {newCount && newCount > 0 && (
        <View style={styles.badge}>
          <Badge
            textColor={colors.inactiveColor}
            backgroundColor={colors.surface}
            count={newCount}
          />
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

export default DrawerItemLabel;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  wrapper: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
  },
  text: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
  },
  badge: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 96,
    top: -3
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[Mikołaj Wittbrodt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15032294/miko%C5%82aj-wittbrodt)'s idea works reliably, not sure if there's any other way. Below is a simpler example:

```js
<Drawer.Navigator
  screenOptions={{ drawerActiveTintColor: "#000", fontWeight: "bold" }}
  initialRouteName="Home"
>
  <Drawer.Screen
    name="Edit Games"
    component={EditGamesD}
    options={{
      headerTitle: "Admin",
      headerTitleAlign: "center",
      drawerLabel: () => (
        <View
          style={{
            // backgroundColor: "pink",
            flexDirection: "row",
            alignItems: "center",
            justifyContent: "space-between",
            width: "115%",
          }}
        >
          <Text>MotoMoto</Text>
          <Entypo name="chevron-right" size={25} color="black" />
        </View>
      ),
      drawerIcon: () => (
        <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", gap: "2vw" }}>
          <MaterialIcons name="admin-panel-settings" size={30} color="black" />
          {/* <Entypo name="edit" size={30} color="black" /> */}
        </View>
      ),
    }}
  />
</Drawer.Navigator>
```